# Unable to deploy Laravel 5 code in Filezilla

Tags: php, laravel

I have deployed my Laravel5 code in filezilla. Following are the steps that I followed:

1. Created a sub-domain ehr
2. Created a folder in ehr named as ehr2
3. Pasted all my folders in ehr2
4. Pasted the contents of public folder in ehr2
5. Changed the directories of index.php

But when I open the url I get 404 page error. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is the design already applied or is it the default 404 page?

Comment: is the virtual host for your server properly configured?

Comment: @RobinDirksen Index.php exists and design is there

Answer (score 0):

**Directory Permissions**

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the **storage** and the **bootstrap/cache** directories should be writable by your web server **or Laravel will not run**.

[Oficial Doc on Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you meet

Laravel 5 requirements :

```
- PHP 5.5
- PHP extension Mcrypt
- PHP extension Mbstring
- PHP extension OpenSSL
```

Here two tutorials for you :

[Link 1](http://novate.co.uk/deploy-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-from-heart-internet/)

[Link 2](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5 so it's fine >= 5.4 but if you have Laravel 5.1 you need at least 5.5

Comment: Laravel is 5.0, still I am getting this 404 error and I have followed the same link that you have provided (Link 1)

Comment: the 404 page you got is it from Laravel or from the server ? can you send me the screenshot of error

Comment: I have attached the page